# Regex - Match Character Between Two Elements

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match a single character (%) between two elements `<p></p>`. Given the following HTML I'd want to find a match:

```
<p>%</p>
```

However, the following HTML should not return a match:

```
<p>test</p>
<span>50%<span>
<p>test</p>
```

The problem I am running into is that my regex finds the starting `<p>` and the very last `<\p>` with the % between them and finds the match. Additionally, the regex needs to cope with new lines. Here is my incorrect regex so far:

```
(<p>)(.|\n|\r)*(%)(.|\n|\r)*(<\/p>)
```

Comment: Try this: [`(?<=<p>)[^<]*(%)[^>]*(?=<\/p>)`](https://regex101.com/r/b2fAsX/1)

Comment: That doesn't match when you have the start and end tag on different lines: https://regex101.com/r/Zfpgf7/1

Comment: I updated my comment, it is what are you looking for?

Comment: That's pretty close and probably usable! The only issue is that it misses situations where there are other tags inside the p tags, for example:

https://regex101.com/r/P4m3og/1

Comment: How about this? [`(?<=<p>)(?:[^<]|<[^\/]|<\/[^p]|<\/p[^>])*(%)(?:[^<]|<[^\/]|<\/[^p]|<\/p[^>])*(?=<\/p>)`](https://regex101.com/r/P4m3og/2)

Comment: No, it is a bit different: `<p(?:\s[^>]*)?>(?:(?!<\/?p[\s>])[^%])*%[\s\S]*?<\/p>`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tek7Ro/2).

Comment: However, it is not recommended to use regex here. Use DOM to parse HTML.

Comment: That's perfect @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 0):

For the shown strings, this will do:

```php
<p>(?:(?!<\/?p>)[^%])*%[\d\D]*?<\/p>
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/NP0oYD/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <p>                      '<p>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      <                        '<'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \/?                      '/' (optional (matching the most
                               amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      p>                       'p>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^%]                     any character except: '%'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  %                        '%'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [\d\D]*?                 any character of: digits (0-9), non-digits
                           (all but 0-9) (0 or more times (matching
                           the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <\/p>                    '</p>'
```